# creating a global file in a MPI environemnt

Tags: python, mpi

I am stimulating a distributed application using mpi4py in python.

I need to create a file OUTPUT_FILE, which is accessed by all the processes and should be empty before starting the application.

The problem is mpi4py starts multiple processes. If I give a command to empty the OUTPUT_FILE, all the processes will try to do it. This is not desirable as some data may be lost.

Is it possible to create such a OUTPUT_FILE and if yes, then how ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with `mpi4py` but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

# first open your file / clear it whatever
# with just one of your processes:
if rank == 0:
    myfile = open("myfile", "w")

# have all your processes sync up
comm.Barrier()

if rank != 0:
    # all the other processes can open 
    # in append mode, or whatever
    myfile = open("myfile", "a")

# Carry on, doing science or what have you ;-)
```

I assume you actually want to use the parallel IO support in `MPI.File` but, as I've already said, I'm not terribly familiar with `mpi4py`.